# TeXStudio profile for emacs keybindings?

Tags: latex, tex

Does any have a TeXStudio profile for setting basic emacs keybindings (C-p, C-n, C-b, C-f, etc.)? I know I can manually set them myself, but TeXStudio doesn't deconflict hotkeys and the work would be rather tedious (I'm lazy and would rather use someone else's work than do it myself :) ).

Also, I'm aware this question might not fit exactly in this forum, since it's focus is working in TexStudio (not emacs), but I figured fellow emacs-ers might be aware of the solution I'm seeking.